# How to check the winner of Simple Jquery Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a super simple Tic Tac Toe game using HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. The game is designed for two players. I'm just wondering how I can check if three dots in a row have the same class for either playerOne or playerTwo.

HTML

```
<body>  
  <table>
    <tr></tr>
      <td><div class="dot" id="dot_1"></div></td>
      <td><div class="dot" id="dot_2"></div></td>
      <td><div class="dot" id="dot_3"></div></td>
    <tr></tr>
      <td><div class="dot" id="dot_4"></div></td>
      <td><div class="dot" id="dot_5"></div></td>
      <td><div class="dot" id="dot_6"></div></td>
    <tr></tr>
      <td><div class="dot" id="dot_7"></div></td>
      <td><div class="dot" id="dot_8"></div></td>
      <td><div class="dot" id="dot_9"></div></td>
  </table>
  <div id="clear">Clear</div>
  <div id="instructions">Instructions</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
table{
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  border-spacing:7px;
}
.dot{
  border-radius:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#A8A8A8;
}
.playerOne{
  border-radius:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
.playerTwo{
  border-radius:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
#clear{
  border-radius:50px;
  width:300px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#A8A8A8;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black; 
}
#clear:active{
  box-shadow:none;
}
#instructions{
  border-radius:50px;
  width:300px;
  margin-top:10px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#A8A8A8;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
#instructions:active{
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dot').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('playerOne');
  });
  $('.dot').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).addClass('playerTwo');
  });
  $('#clear').click(function(){
    $('.dot').removeClass('playerOne');
  });
  $('#clear').click(function(){
    $('.dot').removeClass('playerTwo');
  });
  $('#instructions').click(function(){
    alert('Hi')
  });
});
```

Comment: i'd create a 2 dimensional array to keep which dots are occupied and loop that array every time one of the dots is clicked.
alternatively, you could check only the row which is clicked and only for that player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tic-Tac-Toe has simple enough win conditions that you could simply check for all of them:

```
var winSpots = [
  ["dot_1", "dot_2", "dot_3"]
  // More
];
```

The other way would be to check rows first. and loop over the next two rows.

```
var rows = ["dot_1", "dot_4", "dot_7"];

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var row = rows[i];

  // Get the next two elements, calculate them off list
}
```

A cleaner way would be to keep an array of arrays (what you'd think of as a 2D array) and use that to actually hold data, with what is in the HTML only reflecting that.

That would separate game-logic (the board) from presentation (the display) and you could rewrite how the display works without having to change any of the backing code and this is *exactly* the way I'd solve it.

The process to check for a winning condition wouldn't change, however.  You'd just be checking the array rather than checking the DOM.